# ufw and nmap show different result in terms of open ports

Tags: firewalls, nmap, ports

I have set my firewall `ufw` / `firewall` rules as follows:

```
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)

To                                      Action      From
--                                      ------      ----
OpenSSH (22/tcp)                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full (80,443/tcp)                 ALLOW       Anywhere
```

But if I make a `Zenmap`/`nmap` scan it shows me the following ports are open (or also `closed`):

[image]

Why is `ufw` showing me a different result if by defauls all ports are closed except ssh(22) and nginx (80, 443) and why are two `closed` ports shown? shouldn't all other closed ports be also shown then?

Answer (score 2):

To list current open ports, use `netstat -atnp`

for you Zenmap / nmap result. it depends on where did you run the command. same machine / local network/ external network

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I made the scan from an external network. Its also strange that this result only appeared one time. On my other tries I got port 22&80 as open and 443 as closed (as it should be, because of the `ufw` configuration). All other ports (shown by `netstat`) are not shown in the `zenmap` result on my other tries.